# setting upload/space limit for FTP client

Tags: ftp, web, upload

As part of my web hosting plan i've also got a few domain hosted for family and friends. I have my own FTP account with full access and I would like to give FTP to a web designer and a user. Is there a way for restricing uploads larger than a certian size, or setting a size limit on the folder that the FTP access has access to? I'd rather not let them upload files ridiciously big.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the FTP service you have and the server they use, you'll have to ask them directly.